# CustId is primary key and been used in every class file so how I can fetch data member CustId value from List<CommonDTO> list = new ArrayList<>()

Tags: java

How can I fetch `custId` from a list which has a generic interface? I tried fetching `custId` via `list.getClass.getField("custId")` but unfortunately, the value is not coming.

```java
class Emp implements CommonDto {
    private String CustId;
    private String EmpId;
    private String EmpName;
}
class Student implements CommonDto{
    private String CustId;
    private String StudentId;
    private String StudentName;
}
public interface CommonDto {
}
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException {

        Emp emp = new Emp(1 , 100, "ayush");

        List<Emp> temp = new ArrayList<>() ;
        temp.add(emp);

        List<CommonDto> commonList = new ArrayList<>();
        commonList.add(temp);

        for(CommonDto comm : commonList)// is this the right way to fetch CustId 
            
        {
            // fetch cusId from every domain and add it to new list and return that list
        }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the `CustId` field you must first recognize that that field does not belong to the `CommonDTO` class.  Therefore, there is no guarantee that a given instance will have that field.  If every instance is supposed to have the field then move that field to that class to properly model the data.

Given the existing models, there is a `CustId` field in both `Emp` and `Student` but these are NOT the same field.  You can test the data type of a given instance, cast it, and call the appropriate method.

```
public String getCustId(CommonDTO dto) {
  if (dto instanceof Emp) {
    return ((Emp)dto).getCustId();
  }
  if (dto instanceof Student) {
    return ((Student)dto).getCustId();
  }
  return null;
}
```

If you have leeway to alter the data model then you can move `CustId` to the parent class (i.e. CommonDTO).  Let's assume that his class is provided and you cannot change it.  However, you still have leeway to alter the `Emp` and `Student` models.

You could also define a common interface that defines the property via method and have each of the classes implement that interface.

```
public interface Custmor {
  public String getCustId();
}

public class Emp implements Customer {
  private String custId;
  public String getCustId() { return custId; }
  ...
}

public class Student implements Customer {
  private String custId;
  public String getCustId() { return custId; }
  ...
}
```

Then you can handle the data via the interface.

```
public String getCustId(CommonDTO dto) {
  if (dto instanceof Customer) {
    return ((Customer)dto).getCustId();
  }
  return null;
}
```

Alternatively, you could create a `Customer` class that extends the `CommonDTO` and serves as a base class for both of these...

```
public class Customer extends CommonDTO {
  private custId;
  public String getCustId() { return custId; }
  ...
}
```

And alter the `Emp` and `Student` classes to extend this...

```
public class Emp extends Customer { ... }
public class Student extends Customer { ... }
```

In either case (interface or common base class), you can then use `instanceof` to determine if a given `CommonDTO` instance is a `Customer` and cast it to access the method.  You can use the Stream API to easily pull the `custId`s from the `Customer`s in a `List<CommonDTO>`:

```
List<String> customerIds = commonList.stream()
     .filter(c -> c instanceof Customer) // filter out the non-Customer elements out of the streawm
     .map(c -> (Customer)c) // cast the CommonDTO to a Customer
     .map(c -> c.getCustId()) // get the custId
     .collect(Collectors.toList()); // capture the custIds in a List
```

p.s. suggest that you adhere to Java naming conventions (e.g. variable names begin with lower case letter).